# Qual é o melhor método de conexão entre o PHP e o Firebird?

Tags: php, firebird-2.5

Utilizo as funções `ibase_` para conectar e manipular os dados no `Firebird` com o `PHP`. Vi que muitas pessoas também utilizam `pdo_firebird`. A versão do `Firebird` que utilizo é a 2.5. Afinal, estou utilizando o melhor e mais viável método de manipular os dados ou seria melhor mudar para `pdo`?

Surgiu essa dúvida esses dias por ter pesquisado tanto sobre alguns probleminhas no `Firebird` e vi que a maioria dos posts que pesquisei menciona o `pdo`. Também pelo fato de `ibase_` pudesse ser melhor para uso com o `Interbase`, já que o próprio nome já diz.

Comment: Eu uso `pdo_firebird` e funciona muito bem, tenho uma classe que faz a conexão com o mesmo.

Comment: Eduardo, você poderia postar o código desta classe? E você sabe com relação ao desempenho e viabilidade se é melhor mesmo utilizar a `pdo`?

Comment: Posto sim, quanto a desempenho não sei te dizer pois nunca usei de outra maneira.

Answer (score 1):

Segue a classe que tenho:

Connection.class.php

```
    <?php

    class Connection {

        public static $conn;

        //lê o arquivo .ini com as config

        public static function open($name) {
            if (file_exists("config/{$name}.ini")) {
                $db = parse_ini_file("config/{$name}.ini");
            } else {
                throw new exception("Arquivo '$name' nao encontrado");
            }

            $user = isset($db['user']) ? $db['user'] : NULL;
            $pass = isset($db['pass']) ? $db['pass'] : NULL;
            $name = isset($db['name']) ? $db['name'] : NULL;
            $host = isset($db['host']) ? $db['host'] : NULL;
            $type = isset($db['type']) ? $db['type'] : NULL;
            $port = isset($db['port']) ? $db['port'] : NULL;


            switch ($type) {
                case 'pgsql':
                    $port = $port ? $port : '5432';
                    $conn = new PDO("pgsql:dbname={$name}; user={$user}; password={$pass};host=$host;port={$port};");
                    break;
                case 'mysql':
                    $port = $port ? $port : '3306';
                    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host={$host};port={$port};dbname={$name}", $user, $pass);
                    break;
                case 'sqlite':
                    $conn = new PDO("sqlite:{$name}");
                    break;
                case 'ibase':
                    $conn = new PDO("firebird:dbname={$name}", $user, $pass);
                    break;
                case 'oci8':
                    $conn = new PDO("oci:dbname={$name}", $user, $pass);
                    break;
                case 'mssql':
                    $conn = new PDO("mssql:host={$host},1433;dbname={$name}", $user, $pass);
                    break;
            }

            $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

            self::$conn = $conn;
        }

        public static function select($sql) {
            return self::$conn->query($sql);
        }

        public static function exec($sql, $ret_id = false) {
            $retorno = self::$conn->exec($sql);
            if ($ret_id)
                $retorno = self::$conn->lastInsertId();
            return $retorno;
        }

        public static function close() {
            self::$conn = null;
        }

    }
```

ibase.ini

```
host = 
name = localhost/dados/banco.fdb
user = SYSDBA
pass = 1234
type = ibase
```

A chamada da classe ficaria assim:

```
Connection::open('ibase');

$sql = Connection::select('SELECT * FROM banco');//Select

$sql = Connection::exec('INSERT INTO banco (campo) VALUES ('Teste')');//Insert

Connection::close('ibase');
```

Não esquece de adicionar o pacote abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Obrigado amigo pela disponibilidade e dedicação na sua resposta. Vou fazer testes mudando para esta classe, pois estou com probleminhas na hora de receber as `exceptions` criadas no banco de dados utilizando `ibase_`.

Comment: Acredito que irá lhe ajudar, tenho firebird 1.5 de um sistema antigo, e as consultas funcionam muito bem.